# Sort multiIndex python pandas dataframe by the order they appear on another data frame

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame `df` like this:

```
                 a   b
 id   no   name   
T01  101   foo   1  $10
T32  102   bar   2  $30
T10  103   baz   4  $25
```

where the index are `id, no and name`. I have another data frame `df2` with the index order I wish

```
    no
0  103
1  101
2  102
```

I need the data frame to be

```
                 a   b
 id   no   name  
T10  103   baz   4  $25 
T01  101   foo   1  $10
T32  102   bar   2  $30
```

I've seen to use `df.loc[df2.no.values]` and `df.reindex(df2.no)` but since I have multi indexed dataFrame it doesn't seem to work

What should I use to sort `df` in the key `no` with the order in `df2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print df1.reset_index(level=['id','name'])
         .reindex(df2.no)
         .reset_index()
         .set_index(['id','no','name'])

              a    b
id  no  name        
T10 103 baz   4  $25
T01 101 foo   1  $10
T32 102 bar   2  $30
```

If order of levels is not important:

```
print df1.reset_index(level=['id','name'])
         .reindex(df2.no)
         .set_index(['id','name'], append=True)

              a    b
no  id  name        
103 T10 baz   4  $25
101 T01 foo   1  $10
102 T32 bar   2  $30
```

**TIMEING**:

```
In [77]: %timeit df1.unstack([0, 2]).ix[df2.no].stack([1, 2]).swaplevel(0, 1)
10 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit df1.reset_index(level=['id','name']).reindex(df2.no).reset_index().set_index(['id','no','name'])
The slowest run took 4.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.41 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
df.unstack([0, 2]).ix[df2.no].stack([1, 2]).swaplevel(0, 1)
```

#### Explanation

`unstack([0, 2])` puts 1st and 3rd levels of index into [-2, -1] levels of columns.  This isolates the level you care about.

`ix[df2.no]` orders the remaining level in the order you prefer.

`stack([1, 2])` grabs levels from columns and puts them back into the index.

`swaplevel(0, 1)` puts the index levels back in the original order.